# Unexpected token error on document.write (<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>)

Tags: javascript

I have this syntax on my website and every time I open sources tab, there's this error:

> Unexpected token

Here's my syntax, unsure of where to put the 2nd `</script>` tab:

```
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write (<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>)
</script>
```

Comment: `document.write ('<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')`

Comment: so there's no need to close out the first script tab?

Comment: there's only one tag, the other thing that looks like a close tag is a harmless string literal, provided you encoded it as such

Answer (score 0):

You are writing through the `.write` instruction. The strings are behind quote in JavaScript.

Write this:

```
document.write('<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
```

Comment: Might want to point out why the `/` in the `</script>` closing tag needs to be escaped with a backslash.